# Can you flatten a nested JSON structure into a single autobean?

Tags: json, gwt, autobean

Assuming the following JSON structure:

```
{
    \"is_something\": false,
    \"name\": \"Some Name\",
    \"subtype\": {
        \"total\": 0.0
    }
}
```

Instead of creating two autobean interfaces (one for the whole structure and one for the subtype), I would like to have one which contains all the properties.

```
public interface ExampleAutoBean {
    @PropertyName("is_something")
    boolean isSomething();

    String getName();

    @PropertyName("subtype.total")
    double getTotal();
}
```

So, the `getTotal()` method is expected to contain the `total` property of the nested subtype in the JSON structure. I can't find any documentation in the source code or online which states whether or not this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope: AutoBeans are designed to be a mapping from the JSON structure to Java interfaces, plus or minus collections like `List`, `Set`, and `Map` and String encodings of a `long` or a `Date`. Additionally, it is legal to have json like the following:

```
{
    "some.property.with.dots" : "abcd",
    "name" : "wxyz"
}
```

If the `.` character could only be used for traversing into sub-objects, there would be no way to have a getter for the first property.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That is what I suspected, but I could have swore that I saw a post somewhere that suggested this was possible. Oh well. :)

Comment: What you may have seen is the `@Path` annotation, which works in the Editor framework to describe how to traverse getters and setters to find a sub-property to edit. Check out https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors

Comment: Thanks for the link Colin. I discovered the Editor framework last week, and promptly fell in love!